# Wordpress remove_meta_box issue

Tags: wordpress

I run into a problem trying to get remove_meta_box() to work

```
/** remove metabox for catchkathmandu options
     */
    function vpm_remove_meta_box() {
        remove_meta_box( 'catchkathmandu-options', 'post', 'normal' );
        remove_meta_box( 'authordiv' , 'page' , 'normal' ); //removes author
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'vpm_remove_meta_box' );
```

The point is I dont want contributors and authors to edit the site design, so I wanted to remove the catchkathmandu-options. the code obviously does not reflect the condition, the codex for this function supplies the solutions for that but this code at the besic step, still isnt working - I switched back to Twenty Sixteen theme and put in the authordiv section simply to test. But still no dice.

It's added to child theme functions.php

Have I taken the wrong path and am I looking at the wrong thing entirely?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using a theme called "Catch katHmandu", and you want to remove a meta box for everyone except Admins.

Here is the usage of remove meta box:

```
remove_meta_box( $id, $page, $context );
```

And the Reference on the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

As you can read on the codex, $id is the current id of the div that you want to remove. Let's say that you want to remove "Tags box",  if look for its container id you will find:

```
<div id="tagsdiv-post_tag" class="postbox">
  ...
</div>
```

And if you want to remove tags meta box, your code will look like this:

```
if (!is_admin()) :
  function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', 'page', 'normal');
  }
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
endif;
```

Look for the id of the meta box that you want to remove and remplace **"tagdiv-post_tag"** from code above with your id.

**If you like my answer click the top arrow, as a coder it would mean a lot for me. Thanks!**

**EDIT:**

As @AndrewSeabrook say, try using `admin_menu` hook instead of `add_meta_boxes` in your function.

Comment: No this wont do! I said clearly that I had put the authordiv in for test purposes, and have done so as per the normal practice on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/  the function syntax is  the same as I have used - I dont know if it applies to other id's as per the theme-options but - without this the author box is not working either.

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook - this answer contains all of the pieces to your solution.  Primarily, **you are calling your function with the wrong hook**.  You are using `add_meta_boxes` - when the documentation (and all good examples, including this answer), are using the `admin_menu` hook.  This answer doesn't necessarily give you exactly what you asked for, but it actually gives you *more*, and all the pieces you need.